# Deployment of picklist fields to production

Tags: picklist

I have edited some of picklist values and in sandbox existing records got updated with new values. But when I moved the picklist field to production, previous records in production does not get updated with new values. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: If this is values on standard picklists then they do not deploy using change sets, however if you are using an IDE or the deployment tool then they should deploy.

Comment: @DaveHumm That is custom picklist and we are using Jenkins tool for deplyments

Comment: Ok, that is a surprise as it should deploy. Can you add the relevant section of the package.xml please.

Comment: Did you add the value to specific record type?

Comment: @DaveHumm I've included both CustomField and related RecordType in package.xml. I've tested this by moving in another test sandbox. Its worked there. But somehow its not working in production. Changed picklist values got deployed but records are not having new values